# Split character vector with vector of patterns in R

Tags: r, regex, string, split

I'm trying to write a function that builds a matrix by splitting a character vector repeatedly using successive elements in a vector of patterns.

Let's call the function I'm trying to write `str_split_vector()`. Here's an example of the output I'm looking for:

```
char <- c("A & P | B & C @ D",
          "E & Q | F & G @ H",
          "I & R | J & K @ L")
splits <- c(" \\| ", " & ", " @ ")

str_split_vector(char, splits)
#      [,1]     [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,] "A & P"  "B"  "C"  "D" 
# [2,] "E & Q"  "F"  "G"  "H" 
# [3,] "I & R"  "J"  "K"  "L"
```

The `char` vector is split by each pattern in turn, leaving `"A & P"` intact. (Although it might be easiest to manage that last bit with particular regex patterns.)

I've been able to accomplish this task only iteratively, with a pretty ad hoc loop:

```
for(ii in 1:length(splits)) {
  if(ii == 1) {

    char_mat <- matrix(char)
    char_mat <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(char_mat[ , ii], splits[ii]))

  } else {

    char_mat <- cbind(char_mat[ , 1:ii - 1],
                      do.call(rbind, 
                              strsplit(char_mat[ , ii], splits[ii])
                              )
                      )
  }
}
```

That process looks inefficient to me, since I'm "growing" `char_mat` with the repeated `cbind()` calls. Even worse, I find it almost impossible to understand what's going on without actually running the code.

Is there a simpler way to write this, potentially ignoring the requirement that `"A & P"` not be split?

Comment: Where does `str_split_vector` come from? What package?

Comment: Sorry, that's just me proposing a name for this function I'm trying to write. I'll edit the question to make that clear.

Comment: So why `"A & P"` wasn't split too? You have `" & "` in `splits`.

Comment: Like this? `strsplit(char, paste(splits, collapse = "|"))`.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Right, so ideally I would like to be able to remove previously "split off" strings from the next input to `strsplit()`. (Hence `char_mat[ , ii]` in the for loop.)

Comment: @RuiBarradas Yes, thanks. That works if I give up on not splitting `"A & P"`. I'd still like to see if there's a way around that, though. Also, just guessing now, but I imagine having many alternations in a regex pattern (i.e., a long `splits` vector) would seriously decrease performance?

Comment: `do.call(rbind, strsplit(gsub("(.*) \\| (.*) & (.*) @ (.*)", "\\1_\\2_\\3_\\4", char), "_"))` should do.

Comment: @Abdou Thanks, that's a clever approach. It won't perform any splitting on potential non-uniform elements in `char`, but it does answer my question with the example I provided. Happy to accept, if you write it below.

Comment: @coletl, please feel free to accept the provided answer. My provided solution is added to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the following is what you want. No loops.

```
str_split_vector <- function(x, y){
    s <- strsplit(x, paste(y, collapse = "|"))
    do.call(rbind, s)
}

str_split_vector(char, splits)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,] "A"  "P"  "B"  "C"  "D" 
#[2,] "E"  "Q"  "F"  "G"  "H" 
#[3,] "I"  "R"  "J"  "K"  "L"
```

An approach that uses grouping and won't perform any splitting on the first `&` is the following:

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(gsub("(.*) \\| (.*) & (.*) @ (.*)", "\\1_\\2_\\3_\\4", char), "_"))
```

It basically replaces the characters you wish to split on with an underscore and then splits on those underscores.